# How to make image follow mouse cursor

Tags: javascript, gsap

I have set up this code where the image follows the mouse cursor. However, for some reason it is not working properly on the second container.

https://codepen.io/stefanomonteiro/pen/jOarjgX

PS: Irrelevant: Stackoerflow first force me to pste the code instead of only codepen link. Now it says it is mostly text. This companies should relly less on bots. It gets annoying sometines :)

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.container')

items.forEach((el) => {
  const image = el.querySelector('img')
  
  el.addEventListener('mouseenter', (e) => {
    gsap.to(image, { autoAlpha: 1 })
  })
  
   el.addEventListener('mouseleave', (e) => {
    gsap.to(image, { autoAlpha: 0 })
  })
  
  el.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    gsap.set(image, { x: e.pageX, y: e.pageY })
  })
})
```

```css
.container {
  display:inline-block;
  background:#ff0000;
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
}
.container:nth-child(2){
  background: #00ff00;
}

.container img.swipeimage {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 9;
  opacity: 0;
  visibily: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.9.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <img class="swipeimage" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
  
  <div class="text">
    <h1>One</h1>
  </div>
  
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img class="swipeimage" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
  
  <div class="text">
    <h1>Two</h1>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `.container img.swipeimage` to `top: 0;` in your CSS, otherwise it inherits half of its height (`height` + `transform: translateY(-50%)`)

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.container')

items.forEach((el) => {
  const image = el.querySelector('img')
  
  el.addEventListener('mouseenter', (e) => {
    gsap.to(image, { autoAlpha: 1 })
  })
  
   el.addEventListener('mouseleave', (e) => {
    gsap.to(image, { autoAlpha: 0 })
  })
  
  el.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    gsap.set(image, { x: e.pageX, y: e.pageY })
  })
})
```

```css
.container {
  display:inline-block;
  background:#ff0000;
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
}
.container:nth-child(2){
  background: #00ff00;
}

.container img.swipeimage {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  top: 0;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 9;
  opacity: 0;
  visibily: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.9.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <img class="swipeimage" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
  
  <div class="text">
    <h1>One</h1>
  </div>
  
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img class="swipeimage" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
  
  <div class="text">
    <h1>Two</h1>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Hm, it works perfectly. Though, I am still confused why it worked on the first container.

Comment: `position: absolute` needs a `top` and `left` property, otherwise he just guesses its position. While i'm not sure how `gsap` works, I can only imagine it stacks images waiting for display, for that stack, not having a relative/absolute top prop relation, puts the two images together (like a display: block) intstead of piling them at the same origin, and you end up with the first image at top 0, and the second at top 50%, instead of piled both top: 0 then moving its origin with transform